# Is there a verb for "adding something in front"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I was wondering if there exists a verb that is equivalent to saying 'adding something in front'.

For example, if I have the numbers 1234, then I *add in front* 9 and I will get 91234.

Answer (score 22):

I think you're looking for the word [prepend](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepend), as in

> ...when I prepend '9' I will have '91234'

You could also use [prefix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prefix#Verb), the verb, but I prefer prepend for your usage.

Comment: Ah, yeah that is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Although *prepend* is widely used in the context of computer programming, you won't find it in many dictionaries - and if you did it would be listed as computer jargon. 
For all other uses, use *prefix*

Comment: Also, note that the opposite of "to prepend" would be "to append".

Comment: @gpr, okay thanks that clears it up. But I was indeed looking for a verb to name a function in a computer program, so in this case it's prefect for me :)

Answer (score 4):

I shall say it as follows:

> If I have the number 1234, then I ***prefix*** 9 and I will get 91234.